# Does this linear algebra construction based on a graph have a name, and where has it been studied?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, graph-theory, quantum-mechanics

In the paper *[Kochen-Specker set with seven contexts](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6012)* by Lisonek, Badziag, Portillo and Cabello, the following construction is used :

[image]

**Question :** Have such constructions been used elsewhere, and if so what are recommended papers and books on that topic ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a close relative of the Hamming graph: Vertices of the Hamming graph in question are $2-$element subsets of $\{1,\dots,7\}$. Edges join vertices
corresponding to subsets intersecting in an element. Your graph is the Hamming graph with "overlaid edges" (two vertices are adjacent if they are on a straight segment).

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks close indeed. And do you know if the linear algebra interpretation on top (finite lines as bases in particular) has been made a long time ago ? Thank you.

Comment: An easy answer is: No.